# Share image from gallery into your application

Tags: android, android-intent, share, gallery

I once managed to display my application in the gallery share bar, i need this again, so i can share an image and put this in the ImageView. But i could not figure out / find on the internet how to do this. How do i accomplish this?

I also want to make a popup asking if its a newsitem or a agenda item you are trying to create when sharing it to my application. Because i have 2 items that are able to recieve images, is this possible ?

**for example:**

With photo:

[image: With photo]

Without photo:

[image]

Comment: `to display my application in the gallery share bar`. ???? What is a gallery share bar?

Comment: @greenapps when you click on share you can choose applications i want my application in there.

Comment: You have to arrange that in the manifest file of your app with an intent filter.for action view.

Comment: @greenapps any idea how?

Comment: Yes. But i prefer you do a little googling on the words i used.

Comment: `SELECTEER EEN FOTO`. The picture is already selected in the Gallery app. So makes no sense to do that again. Better put something in that's going to happen with it. Also its a bad idea to offer a delete possibility. The user better deletes files with the gallery app itself. As you want to offer the user two choices you better put the choises in it.

Comment: @greenapps i googled the shit out of this question, i dont post questions if i havent already tried, its also not my discision but the one of my boss, he wants ppl to be able to take a picture and directly from there upload it to the website

Comment: `intent filter for images`.

Comment: `to take a picture and directly from there upload it to the website`. That is something completely different.